# eval( MPI_Run( MPI_cc('xbasic'), 2,machines) ) gives me error

Tags: matlab, installation, mpi

I want to use mpiMatlab for my algorithm,i have problem in INSTALLING AND RUNNING of it.
According to this link can any one help me:

http://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/isr/matlabmpi/matlabmpi.html

when i wrote this command in matlab:

```
eval( MPI_Run( MPI_cc('xbasic'), 2,machines) );
```

It gives me this error:

```
??? Undefined function or
method 'MPI_cc' for input
arguments of type 'char'.

Error in ==> Untitled at 1
eval( MPI_Run(
MPI_cc('xbasic'), 2,machines)
);
```

Comment: check your path so that the MPI_cc function is visible

Answer (score 0):

The error messages suggests that the source code folder is not defined in your MATLABPATH.

Try

```
which MPI_cc
```

To see if you can see the code.

Then try to walk before you run.

Does this work?

```
eval( MPI_Run('xbasic', 2,machines) );
```

Next does this work?

```
MPI_cc('xbasic');
```

Once all these steps are working then you can try your original code.

```
eval( MPI_Run( MPI_cc('xbasic'), 2,machines) );
```